# Help selecting fields in flow - Primary Campaign on Opportunity Record

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, formula-field, campaign-member

I have been unsuccessful recreating a flow that populates the primary campaign source on the opportunity record before save. I followed step by step instructions however I can not correctly identify which fields are needed  in Get Records portion of the flow.
[image: Pic from Instructions]

I need to identify the correct field and value used in the pic.
Field: ContactId   Value:  $Report > Explorer ???
What is $Report > Explorer?